# How to add multiple events in one button Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, file-upload

I want to pick and upload image from gallery with one button in the same time for Firebase. But the first when i clicked the button it picked up image and the second time when i clicked it uploads. How can i fix it that when i clicked it should be go to gallery and save to Firebase Storage

```
  idgir.setOnLongClickListener {
            


            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                ) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                        this,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                    )
                ) {
                    Snackbar.make(
                        view,
                        "Permission needed for gallery!",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
                    ).setAction("Give Permission") {
                        permissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    }.show()
                } else {
                    permissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

                }

            } else {
                val intentToGallery =
                    Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
                activityResultLauncher.launch(intentToGallery)
            }






            val uuid = UUID.randomUUID()
            val imageName = "$uuid.jpg"

            val reference = storage.reference
            val imagereference = reference.child("images").child(imageName)

            if (selectedPicture != null) {
                imagereference.putFile(selectedPicture!!).addOnSuccessListener {




                    val uploadPictureReference =
                        storage.reference.child("images").child(imageName)
                    uploadPictureReference.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
```

private fun registerLauncher() {

```
        activityResultLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
                if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    val intentFromResult = result.data
                    if (intentFromResult != null)
                        selectedPicture = intentFromResult.data
                    selectedPicture?.let {
                        binding.idgir.setImageURI(it)
                    }


                }

            }

        permissionLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { result ->
                if (result) {
                    val intentToGallery =
                        Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
                    activityResultLauncher.launch(intentToGallery)



                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Permission needed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                }

            }


    }


}
```

Comment: where is the activityResultLauncher callback method? You will receive data from there.. In the callback you've to upload

Comment: As Gobu CSG mentioned in his comment, you have to use activityResultLauncher in order to receive a callback. Did you do that? However, here you can find a [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) that can help you achieve that.

Comment: Firstly thanks for both of you to response. I updated my question so i added there my activity result launcher

Answer (score 0):

Where you are launching gallery to pick image in else block if permission in granted in else check is selectedPicture is null if null than pick image else upload image.